# React calling functions resunting in loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to understand why this results in a loop :

```js
<button onClick={this.moveRight()}>
```

but this does not:

```js
<button onClick={this.moveRight}>
```

Also my my problem is to call a function from another function that is also resulting a loop, why ?

```js
anyfunction(){
anotherfunction();
}

anotherfunction(){

        if (this.state.something >1 ){
            this.setState(PrevState => {
                PrevState.something = PrevState.something -1
                return {something = PrevState.something};
            });
            this.anyfunction()

        }
    }
```

Why the if does not break the loop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `this.moveRight()` calls itself, then unless you put a condition to stop the recursion, it'll continue to do so. Also, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59941546/2950032) tells you how to assign an event handler correctly.

> Also my problem is to call a function from another function. That is also resulting a loop, why?

`this.setState` is async, so if you want the value of `this.state.something` to be set before you call `this.anyfunction()`, then you'll need to do something like:

```
function anotherfunction() {
  if (this.state.something > 1) {
    this.setState(
      PrevState => {
        return { something: PrevState.something - 1 };
      },
      () => {
        this.anyfunction();
      }
    );
  }
}
```

which says that call `this.anyFunction` once you're done doing the state change that I asked for. More on that [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#why-is-setstate-giving-me-the-wrong-value).

Comment: Why i get this error when i try to do arrow function like u did ? ESLint: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.(no-unused-expressions)

Comment: How should I call the function to have it run only once and avoid the loop ? or how could i stop this loop ?

Comment: @AndreAndriole I don't know the context of the error, so I can't answer it. If you want to call it only once, then why are you calling it again inside?

Comment: I want to call it 3 times but this.anyfunction() calls a billion times. What should i write to call it once ?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why

```
<button onClick={this.moveRight()}>
```

results in a loop is having the parenthesis calls the function, rather than setting onClick to the functions reference.

The second issue is also resulting in a loop because the function's both call each other, if `this.state.something > 1` never evaluates to false.

Comment: The if is going false, i checked using debugger. It ignores the if and keeps looping.

So placing parethesis means "call this function" and not empty parameters like java ?